# Coldfusion cfhttp Connection Failure: Status code unavailable error with HTTP url not HTTPS

Tags: coldfusion, connection, cfhttp

We are running Coldfusion 2016 and I have a cfhttp tag that is returning the following error: **Connection Failure: Status Code Unavailable**. I've read a lot of threads on this error but they all seem to be for cfhttp tags that are calling an HTTPS url. Ours is calling an HTTP url on a development server. I can paste the url it's calling into a browser and pull it up just fine.

```
<cfhttp result="TestResponse" method="post" url="http://testurl/ratecall1.cfm" throwonerror="Yes">
<cfhttpparam type="FormField" name="apiId" value="userid" />
<cfhttpparam type="FormField" name="apiPassword" value="password" />
```

I've tried adding redirect="false" and that had no effect. Nothing on the development server is HTTPS.

On our production server the same cfhttp tag IS calling an HTTPS url and it works just fine.

Below is the stack trace it spits out:

```
Browser     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
Remote Address      155.186.228.190
Referrer    
Date/Time   08-Nov-21 01:48 PM
Stack Trace
at cftest2ecfm1329596319.runPage(D:/Domains/JupiterAuto/test.cfm:47) at cfApplication2ecfc1154535953$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(D:/Domains/JupiterAuto/Application.cfc:132)

coldfusion.tagext.net.HttpTag$HttpConnectionFailureException: Connection Failure: Status code unavailable
    at coldfusion.tagext.net.HttpTag.connHelper(HttpTag.java:1303)
    at coldfusion.tagext.net.HttpTag.doEndTag(HttpTag.java:1394)
    at cftest2ecfm1329596319.runPage(D:\Domains\JupiterAuto\test.cfm:47)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:254)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:743)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:573)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:3851)
    at cfApplication2ecfc1154535953$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(D:\Domains\JupiterAuto\Application.cfc:132)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:493)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:426)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:389)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:340)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:235)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:654)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:443)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:413)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:114)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:307)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:480)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:43)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:153)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:60)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:223)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:134)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doNext(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:770)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doHttpServletRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:339)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doFusionRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:215)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.handle(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:807)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorCoreFilter.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor76.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.filter.FusionReactorStaticFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorStaticFilter.java:53)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.pointcuts.NewFilterChainPointCut$1.invoke(NewFilterChainPointCut.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:356)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:544)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried putting `<cfdump var="#TestResponse#">` after the `</cfhttp>` tab but didnt get any more output than the above stack trace. I think this worked at one time on the development server, I don't know why it would have stopped working. I am at a loss as to what to do here. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you hit http://testurl/ratecall1.cfm from a browser on the system hosting ColdFusion?  Are you able to hit a different non-CF page like a simple HTML page using CFHTTP?

Comment: Yes I can do both of those things.

Comment: Let me correct that, I CANNOT hit testurl/ratecall1.cfm from a browser on the actual server that Coldfusion is hosted on. I can hit a non-CF page using CFHTTP however.

Comment: Non-CF page on the *same* box or different one? Can you telnet to port 80 on the testurl box?

Comment: I cannot hit a non-CF page on the same box, I get "page cannot be displayed". I can hit a non-CF page on a different box.

Comment: I can telnet to port 80 on a different box, I cannot telnet to port 80 on the same box.

Comment: Weird. I can't think of why you wouldn't be able to call a page ON the server - yet be able to access from *outside* (same page, same port).  Any difference using IP:portNum instead of server name, i.e. testurl. Same with localhost and/or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Could be the ColdFusion server is unable to resolve testurl.  What IP does testurl resolve to from the ColdFusion host:  PING testurl

Comment: When I attempt to ping testurl from the box Coldfusion is hosted on the request times out every time. Although it does display an IP address that it is trying to ping. When I ping it from outside it comes back immediately.

Comment: I should add that this is Windows Server 2008 R2 and we have multiple sites on the box such as demo.testurl, marketing.testurl, services.testurl etc. All of the sites are HTTP. On our production box we have the same setup except all the sites are HTTPS. On the production box I can connect to another page on the same box. The only difference I am aware of between the two boxes is that on one the URL's are HTTPS and on the other HTTP.

Comment: I should also add that if I add the testurl domain to the hosts file then I can browse to it and ping it on the same box, an entry such as nnn.nn.nnn.nn demo.testurl.